# Leer fichero por bloques ¿Como optimizarlo? ver final del post

Tags: java, string, archivo, split

Buenos días querida comunidad.
Soy un estudiante de desarrollo de aplicaciones plataforma y me he encontrado con un problema en clase que me trae algún que otro dolor de cabeza, a ver si alguien puede ayudarme o darme alguna pista.

Tengo el siguiente archivo (sudokus.txt):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si os dais cuenta siempre sigue el mismo patrón, se parte con % y entonces tenemos que el primer numero de la fila, en la imagen de ejemplo = 7, sería el nivel de dificultado, el segundo valor seria una string que seria una descripción de la dificultad = Medium (Level 7), luego salta de linea y tenemos que toda la linea es una cadena que seria el problema y la siguiente la solución.

Si os dais cuenta, estamos hablando de una aplicacion que habla sobre sudokus, dejo una imagen del modelo.

```
package model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Sudoku implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private Integer nivel;
    private String descripcion;
    private String problema;
    private String solucion;
    private Set historials = new HashSet(0);

    public Sudoku() {
    }

    /**
     * @param nivel
     * @param descripcion
     * @param problema
     * @param solucion
     */
    public Sudoku(Integer nivel, String descripcion, String problema, String solucion) {
        this.nivel = nivel;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.problema = problema;
        this.solucion = solucion;
    }

    /**
     * @param nivel
     * @param descripcion
     * @param problema
     * @param solucion
     * @param historials
     */
    public Sudoku(Integer nivel, String descripcion, String problema, String solucion, Set historials) {
        this.nivel = nivel;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.problema = problema;
        this.solucion = solucion;
        this.historials = historials;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getNivel() {
        return this.nivel;
    }

    public void setNivel(Integer nivel) {
        this.nivel = nivel;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return this.descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getProblema() {
        return this.problema;
    }

    public void setProblema(String problema) {
        this.problema = problema;
    }

    public String getSolucion() {
        return this.solucion;
    }

    public void setSolucion(String solucion) {
        this.solucion = solucion;
    }

    public Set getHistorials() {
        return this.historials;
    }

    public void setHistorials(Set historials) {
        this.historials = historials;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //TODO Care with historial
        return "Sudoku [id=" + id + ", nivel=" + nivel + ", descripcion=" + descripcion + ", problema=" + problema
                + ", solucion=" + solucion + ", historials=" + historials + "]";
    }
}
```

El problema básicamente es que tengo que partir el fichero como por bloques, donde cada 3 filas empezaría un nuevo objeto Sudoku.

se recorrerme el fichero y todo, pero estoy estancado en cuanto tengo que partirlo y crearme el fichero.

He intentado algunas cosas y el concepto lo tengo claro, pero no me quiero hacer ni un modulo de 3 con un contador porque es feo y si hay una linea en blanco el programa generaría un error, etc.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import globals.Constants;
import model.Sudoku;;

public class TrasladoORM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sudoku sudokuToAdd;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Constants.FileNames.SUDOKU_LIST.getName()))) {
            String line;
            List<Sudoku> SudokuList = new ArrayList<>();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //partir por % para empezar nuevo objeto
                //guardar el: [0] nivel [1] descripcion
                //siguiente line: [0] problema
                //siguiente line: [0] solucion
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Código funcionando (posiblemente lo mas sucio que he hecho nunca):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import exception.SudokuException;
import globals.Constants;
import model.Sudoku;
import persistence.SudokuDAO;;

public class TrasladoORM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SudokuDAO dao = new SudokuDAO();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Constants.FileNames.SUDOKU_LIST.getName()))) {
            String line;
            List<Sudoku> sudokuList = new ArrayList<>();
            int contadorSudoku = -1, contadorLinea = 0;
            boolean problem = true;
            String[] splitedLine;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(contadorLinea % 3 == 0) {
                    contadorSudoku++;
                    splitedLine = line.split(" ");
                    sudokuList.add(new Sudoku());
                    sudokuList.get(contadorSudoku).setNivel(Integer.parseInt(splitedLine[1]));
                    sudokuList.get(contadorSudoku).setDescripcion(splitedLine[2]+splitedLine[3]+splitedLine[4]);
                }else {
                    if(problem) {
                        sudokuList.get(contadorSudoku).setProblema(line);
                        problem = false;
                    }else {
                        sudokuList.get(contadorSudoku).setSolucion(line);
                        problem = true;
                    }
                }
                contadorLinea++;
            }
            for (Sudoku s : sudokuList) {
                try {
                    dao.insertarSudoku(s);
                } catch (SudokuException e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

output:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si el fichero siempre tiene la misma estructura es fácil, cada 3 lineas sabes que tiene un nuevo sudoku, pero si puede tener lineas en blanco como comentas quizás se complique un poco más. Lo importante te diría que es garantizar que los ficheros tengan una estructura fija, lo que te permite poder parsearlo.

Comment: Es eso, si siempre sigue el mismo patrón haces un contador que se incremente cada vez que lea una linea y cuando este sea modulo de 3 empiezas a crear otro Sudoku, pero me gustaría una manera un poco mas bonita y robusta de hacerlo, había pensado incluso en usar expresiones regulares, pero las tengo algo verdes y me corre algo de prisa. Muchas gracias por tu aportación!

Comment: Es que si el fichero siempre tiene la misma estructura, no tienes porqué utilizar expresiones regulares ya que cada dato siempre está en su sitio. Lo más sencillo, y no por eso no quiere decir que sea feo, es utilizar un contador, y cada 3 lineas crear un nuevo objeto sudoku. En ingeniería de software existe un principio de diseño muy importante conocido como KISS (keep it simple, stupid!) lo que se traduce como, "mantenlo simple, estúpido", y realmente yo trato de tenerlo en mente siempre que diseño una arquitectura. Que no te asuste lo sencillo, muchas veces es la mejor solución.

Comment: Con un contador lo tienes hecho, es muy sencillo. Sólo tienes que poner un contador que se incremente cada vez que leas una línea y hacer un if de i%3==0

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano, hola pablo, ya se que es fácil, mira, arriba lo he hecho pero me parece un código un poco sucio que digamos, hay algo que se podría optimizar y hacer mejor?

Comment: @E.Betanzos lo he hecho al final siguiendo tu consejo, pero me parece un poco feo el código, sobretodo esta flag boolean que he tenido que poner para controlar si es solución o problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira, te estoy compartiendo una mejora a tu solución para que veas que no tienes que utilizar ninguna bandera para saber si es solución o problema, con el contador de linea es más que suficiente. Así el código mejora un poco en legibilidad. Espero que te sirva.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SudokuDAO dao = new SudokuDAO();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Constants.FileNames.SUDOKU_LIST.getName()))) {
        String line;
        List<Sudoku> sudokuList = new ArrayList<>();
        int contadorLinea = 0;
        String[] splitedLine;
        Sudoku tempSudoku = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            contadorLinea++;

            if (contadorLinea == 1) {
                tempSudoku = new Sudoku();

                splitedLine = line.split(" ");
                tempSudoku.setNivel(Integer.parseInt(splitedLine[1]));
                tempSudoku.setDescripcion(splitedLine[2]+splitedLine[3]+splitedLine[4]);

                sudokuList.add(tempSudoku);
            } else if (contadorLinea == 2) {
                tempSudoku.setProblema(line);
            } else if (contadorLinea == 3) {
                tempSudoku.setSolucion(line);
                contadorLinea = 0;
            }
        }

        for (Sudoku s : sudokuList) {
            try {
                dao.insertarSudoku(s);
            } catch (SudokuException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Fíjate que el último `else if (contadorLinea == 3)` no hace falta, pero te lo puse para que quede más claro lo que se hace.

Comment: Genial!, me gusta bastante mas que mi solución, estaba tan centrado en hacerlo con un módulo que no veía que se podía hacer así de fácil.